# Android MultiPart HttpPost takes 20secs to execute request

Tags: android, multipartform-data, playframework-2.2

I do file upload from Android to Heroku (PlayFramework 2.2 Java)

I upload a small picture with MultipartEntity and HttpPost.

My request is received and processed by the server instantly, but the response.execute(..) takes 20s to terminate.

I used put a loader on the file upload with this
http://toolongdidntread.com/android/android-multipart-post-with-progress-bar/

The file uploads instantly. The server gets it and send its response instantly.

Any idea ?

```
   final AsyncTask task=new AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String>() {

       public ProgressBar uploadSeekBar= (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
       int size;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String result = "";
            final String url = ResourcesUtil.SERVER_URL+"/submit/";
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

            CustomMultiPartEntity multipartEntity = new CustomMultiPartEntity(new CustomMultiPartEntity.ProgressListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void transferred(long num)
                {
                    publishProgress((int) num);
                }
            });

            try {
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

                ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFilePath).compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, bos);
                byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();
                ByteArrayBody bab = new ByteArrayBody(data, imageFilePath); // Your image file

                multipartEntity.addPart("picture", bab);
                multipartEntity.addPart("totem.id", new StringBody(totemId));
                multipartEntity.addPart("totem_name", new StringBody(totemName));
                multipartEntity.addPart("lat", new StringBody(ScanActivity.location.getLatitude()+""));
                multipartEntity.addPart("lon", new StringBody(ScanActivity.location.getLongitude()+""));
                multipartEntity.addPart("message", new StringBody(((EditText) findViewById(R.id.flashAnswer)).getText().toString()));
                multipartEntity.addPart("name", new StringBody(((EditText) findViewById(R.id.flasher_name)).getText().toString()));
                multipartEntity.addPart("mail", new StringBody(((EditText) findViewById(R.id.flasher_email)).getText().toString()));
                httppost.setEntity(multipartEntity);

                size= (int) multipartEntity.getContentLength();

                uploadSeekBar.setMax(size);
                uploadSeekBar.setProgress(0);
                uploadSeekBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                Log.e("request","begin");
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(httppost);
                Log.e("request","end");

                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()!=200){
                    return response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()+"";
                }

                result = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

                entity.consumeContent();
                client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                Loggr.log("Error request flash", "error flash");

                try {
                    multipartEntity.writeTo(bytes);
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                    Loggr.log("Error logging flash form", "error flash");
                }

                String content = bytes.toString();

                Loggr.logData("Error flash submit ", "error flash", e.toString());
                Loggr.logData("Error flash submit data", "error flash", content);
            }
            return result;
        }


       @Override
       protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
           super.onProgressUpdate(values);
           uploadSeekBar.setProgress(values[0]);
           Log.e("progress",values[0]+"");
       }

   }.execute();
```

LOGCAT :

```
04-23 09:59:18.355    3580-3798/com.wimha.app E/request﹕ begin
04-23 09:59:18.746    3580-3580/com.wimha.app E/progress﹕ 2
04-23 09:59:18.800    3580-3580/com.wimha.app E/progress﹕ 34
......
04-23 09:59:19.035    3580-3580/com.wimha.app E/progress﹕ 11020
04-23 09:59:19.035    3580-3580/com.wimha.app E/progress﹕ 11022
04-23 09:59:30.757    3580-3798/com.wimha.app E/request﹕ end
```

---

**EDIT :**  Other try with LoopJ library

```
private void sendRequest(final String totemId, final String totemName) {

    final ProgressBar uploadSeekBar= (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);


    final String url = ResourcesUtil.SERVER_URL+"/submit/";
    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    client.setTimeout(20000);

    File myFile = new File(imageFilePath);
    RequestParams params = new RequestParams();


    try {
        params.put("picture", myFile);

    } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {

        Loggr.log("Error request flash file not found", "error flash");

    }
    params.put("totem.id", totemId);
    params.put("totem_name", totemName);
    params.put("lat", ScanActivity.location.getLatitude()+"");
    params.put("lon", ScanActivity.location.getLongitude()+"");
    params.put("message", ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.flashAnswer)).getText().toString());
    params.put("name", ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.flasher_name)).getText().toString());
    params.put("mail", ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.flasher_email)).getText().toString());

    client.post(this,url,params,new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
        public boolean setSize;

        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
            Loggr.log("Submitting","created flash");
            uploadSeekBar.setProgress(0);
            uploadSeekBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
            super.onSuccess(statusCode, headers, responseBody);
            Loggr.log("Submitted","created flash");
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(findViewById(R.id.flasher_email).getWindowToken(), 0);
            handleResponse(new String(responseBody));

            Log.e("success",new String(responseBody));
        }

        @Override
        public void onProgress(int bytesWritten, int totalSize) {
            super.onProgress(bytesWritten, totalSize);
            Log.e("progress",bytesWritten+"");
            if(!setSize){
                setSize=true;
                uploadSeekBar.setMax(totalSize);
            }
            uploadSeekBar.setProgress(bytesWritten);

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
            super.onFailure(statusCode, headers, responseBody, error);
            Log.e("fail",statusCode+" "+responseBody.toString());

            Loggr.logData("Error flash submit ", "error flash", responseBody.toString());
        }

    });

}
```

**Logcat** :

```
04-22 20:46:39.832  28314-28314/com.wimha.app E/progress﹕ 968
04-22 20:46:39.843  28314-28314/com.wimha.app E/progress﹕ 1175
04-22 20:46:39.843  28314-28314/com.wimha.app E/progress﹕ 5271
04-22 20:46:39.847  28314-28314/com.wimha.app E/progress﹕ 9367
04-22 20:46:39.859  28314-28314/com.wimha.app E/progress﹕ 13463
04-22 20:46:39.859  28314-28314/com.wimha.app E/progress﹕ 17559
04-22 20:46:39.859  28314-28314/com.wimha.app E/progress﹕ 21655
04-22 20:46:39.859  28314-28314/com.wimha.app E/progress﹕ 24973
04-22 20:46:39.863  28314-28314/com.wimha.app E/progress﹕ 24975
04-22 20:46:39.863  28314-28314/com.wimha.app E/progress﹕ 25011
04-22 20:46:50.461  28314-28314/com.wimha.app E/progress﹕ 74
04-22 20:46:50.574  28314-28332/com.wimha.app I/System.out﹕ URL: http://post.loggr.net/1/logs/totemwimha2/events
04-22 20:46:50.625  28314-28332/com.wimha.app I/System.out﹕ PostStr: text=Submitted&tags=created+flash+android&source=android&apikey=696d22c04aba45b6a1fc2e67e70b6d60
04-22 20:46:50.629  28314-28314/com.wimha.app E/success﹕ {"first_flash":"true","postDate":"2014-04-22","timestamp":"1398192401545"}
```

Comment: You might want to add a log statement after the EntityUtils.toString to see if the server is generating a really long response.

Comment: Another thing... why shutdown the client?

Comment: A json of a hundred chars ...

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bm.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, bos);
byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();
ByteArrayBody bab = new ByteArrayBody(data, "image.jpg"); // Your image file
```

Then, you send the file

```
multipartEntity.addPart("picture", bab);
```

Excuse me for my short answer, if you need a best explication in a while I will can answer better

Comment: Gonna try ..  The idea is to compress again ?  Got the same problem using this lib http://loopj.com/android-async-http/

Comment: Any other idea, how to log what happends here